# Call an http url from model class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to import contact list using google API. One of this example provide by google is

```
print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
```

Here

```
$auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

In this `$auth` gives an url which will be called onclick of `Connect Me`. This is a simple php example example which I want to implement in CodeIgniter. So I have moved this example logic to a model class. Here I want to save url response to DB and then send to a view.
How would to hit the url provided by  `$client->createAuthUrl()` from model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the model from your controller, and then pass the data to the view as defined in the official documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)  and [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) like this:

```
Class YourController Extends CI_Controller
{

.
.
.

function yourFunction()
{
  $this->load->model('Model_yourModel');
  $data['auth'] = $this->Model_yourModel->createAuthUrl();

  $this->load->view('yourView', $data);
}
```

and in `yourView.php` you can use it like this

```
print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
```

Comment: May be because I haven't given complete code:
1. createAuthUrl() method is defined in another class. So $client=Google_Client(). 
2. Are you sure that giving href='$auth' in yourView.php will hit yourFunction() of controller?

Comment: 1. I think i cannot understand what you want to say. If the createAuthUrl() is defined in a model, then you just have to load that Model and call the function as i mentioned above. If it is in another Controller you cannot call it and you should create a Helper instead.

2. If by 'hit' you mean to call it, no i did not say that. 
The $data['auth'] value will have the return value of the yourFunction(). Then in the view, the $auth is the same as $data['auth']. That happens because the Controller is called first and then it loads the View. So the $data['auth'] passes to $auth and not vice versa.